# Proving consistency of OLS estimator in an unfamiliar setting

Tags: least-squares, econometrics, consistency

I'm stuck on two questions, both of which relate to proving the (in)consistency of the standard OLS estimator.

I'm given the following regression model, where $Y_i$ denotes the outcome measure for the $i^{th}$ individual, $D_i$ is a binary treatment indicator (taking on value $0$ conditional on treatment; $1$ conditional on treatment).

$$ Y_i = \alpha + \delta D_i + \pmb{X^{T}_{i}} \theta_i + \epsilon_i  $$

I'm asked to show the following two things: first, that the OLS estimator of $\delta$ is consistent, so long as $Y_i$ and $D_i$ are independent, conditional on $X_i$. Next, I'm supposed to show that OLS is *inconsistent*, if $Y_i$ and $D_i$ are only independent conditional on $X_i$ and an additional covariate $W_i$.

I know the standard proof for the consistency of the OLS estimator, where we end up with the following expression:

$$ \beta +(plim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1/n) X^{T}X')^{-1}(plim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1/n) X^Tu) = 0$$

However, in the proof I'm aware of the intercept is included in the $ \beta X$ matrix product. If I follow similar steps for this question, I end up with:

$$ \beta +(plim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1/n) \delta^{T}\delta')^{-1}(plim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1/n) \delta^T\epsilon) + (plim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1/n) \delta^T X\theta)$$

However, I'm not sure how to show that the final expression is zero. If $Y$ and $D$ are independent conditional on X, does that make: $$(plim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1/n) \delta^T X\theta) = 0$$ If so, why? Moreover, why does this change when $Y_i$ and $D_i$ are independent only an additional covariate? I'm quite confused, so help understanding would be really amazing!

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the point of the question, I think.  The issue isn't whether the estimators converge in probability to the things they estimate, it's whether they estimate the right things. The second estimator is consistent *but for something other than $\delta$*.

Suppose, so as not to prejudice things, we write $\xi=\lim_{n\to\infty} \hat\delta$ in the first question and $\zeta=\lim_{n\to\infty} \hat\delta$ in the second question (limits in probability). The question wants you to show that $\xi=\delta$ and that $\zeta\neq\delta$.

The first one is fairly easy; it follows from OLS consistency. For the second one it's probably easiest to write down a model including $W$ and work out what $\zeta$ is in terms of the coefficients in that model and show it isn't $\delta$.